# TestCafe- TestController is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, testcafe, cucumberjs

I am new to TestCafe world and am trying to implement a framework for TestCafe+CucumberJs. I am not sure what is going wrong but I am getting an error that testcontroller is not defined. I am copying most of the files that show the path of e2e test flow in the framework. Implemented similar framework for Protractor so want to continue designing e2e tests in a similar fashion. Please let me know in case of additional information required.
**TestCafe Version- 2.2.0**

**Feature File:**

```
@documentManagementTest0
   *Scenario: Search Document section validate
    Given User is on Document Management Page*
```

**StepDefination:**

```
import { Given, When, Then }  from "cucumber";
import page from '../page-objects/documentManagementPO'
import { t } from "testcafe";

Given('User is on Document Management Page', function () {
    page.DocumentManagementPO.login(t);
    page.DocumentManagementPO.get(t);

});
```

**PageObjectFile:**

```
import { Selector, t, testcafe } from 'testcafe';
import { testData } from '../testData/data.json';
import {Base} from '../support/BasePO';


export default class DocumentManagementPO extends Utils{

    async login(t){
        await loginTo(t, "tstEnv");
    }

    async get(t){
        await loadApp(t, 'tstApp');
    }
```

**UtilsClass**

```
import { Selector, t, testcafe } from 'testcafe';
import { testData } from '../testData/data.json';
export class Base {

    async loadApp(t, app) {

        const dropdown = Selector("portal-.dropdown:not(.userProfile)");
        await t.click(dropdown);
        const appElement = Selector('ul > li'+ app);
        await t.click(appElement);

    }

    get loginForm() {
        return {
            get userId() {
                return Selector('[name="UID"]');
            },
            get password() {
                return Selector('[name="PASSWORD"]');
            },
            get loginButton() {
                return Selector('input[type="image"]');
            }
        };
    }


    async loginTo(t,testEnv) {
        var baseUrl;

        if(testEnv === 'tst1'){
            baseUrl = testData.tst1;
        }
        else if(testEnv === 'tst2'){
            baseUrl = testData.tst2;
        }
        else{
            baseUrl = testData.DevUrl;
        }
        await t.navigateTo(baseUrl);
        await t.typeText(this.loginForm.userId, testdata.userName);
        await t.typeText(this.loginForm.password, testData.password);
        await t.click(this.loginForm.loginButton);

    }

}
```

Comment: Error snapshot-Scenario: 'Search Document section validate # e2e\features\documentManagement.feature:5
   × Before # e2e\support\hooks.js:46
       ReferenceError: testController is not defined
           at ***\e2e\support\world.js:16:27
           at <anonymous>:null:null '

Comment: The information you provided is insufficient to determine the cause of the problem. Please provide the full code of your project.

Comment: ok i have figured out the exact pain point am having. In the package.json my script to run test looks like this:'''  "test": "./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js.cmd e2e/**/*.feature --require e2e/**/*.js --tags @tcpractice --require-module @babel/register -f json:./reports/cucumber_report.json --app-init-delay 10000 --page-load-timeout 10000 --selector-timeout 10000 --assertion-timeout 10000", ''' This bit is causing issues in the above script ** ''' --require-module @babel/register ''' ** Can this part of the script be used somewhere else in the TestCafe setup?

Comment: Hello @aleks-pro, can you please let me know how to share code of my project? i can't see any option of attaching zip file here?

Comment: @aleks-pro- please check if you can access this repo https://github.com/PrasKams/TestCafe-BDD All the code is present there as you have requested.

Comment: Hello @Wolvoine41, I have no access to the repository. Please [make it public](https://help.github.com/en/articles/setting-repository-visibility#making-a-repository-public) or add me as a collaborator.

Comment: Hello @aleks-pro, i have made this repo public and added you as collaborator, please check if its you i have added as collaborator, else i have made the repo public anyways. Please provide your insights on the problem

Comment: Hello @Wolvoine41, now, I have access to the repository. I will check it shortly.

Comment: I would go for something already created on GitHub.  This repo is exactly what you're after - Testcafe with Cucumber
https://github.com/kiwigrid/gherkin-testcafe

Comment: @Wolvoine41, sorry for the late response. Could you please update the [`test`](https://github.com/PrasKams/TestCafe-BDD/blob/master/package.json#L36) script in the `package.json` file? This command refers to the `e2e` directory but there is no such folder in the repository you provided.

Comment: @aleks-pro- sorry for the late reply as well, i have added the e2e folder and created other sub-folders and copied rest of the relevant files in each folder under e2e, please ignore the folders present under root. Only refer to folders and files under e2e.

Comment: @MarioGalea-- am using this repo, https://github.com/rquellh/testcafe-cucumber which has proper cucumber.js wrapper and not just gherkin language support.The repo which you mentioned didn't reported each line from scenario in the results html reports, so have to find another solution which shows detailed report. Hence started using different flavour of cucumberjs+testcafe

Comment: Sorry if it's not needed now but I see you use:
Given('User is on Document Management Page', function () {});
But you need this:
Given('User is on Document Management Page', async (t: TestController) => {}); Actually you need to give test controller to function.

Comment: @ElenaGook, sure thank you very much, let me use this and get back to you if it helps. It is still needed, thx for sharing.